# Android: why nothing shows up on screen?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewanimator

and thanks for your help.
I am trying to use a ViewAnimator tho show different views on screen.

So:

- I create the VievAnimator,
- I add 2 Views (LinearLayouts in this case) to ViewAnimator,
- I set setContentView(viewAnimator);
- I call viewAnimator.showNext();

But nothing shows on screen...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public DataBaseHelper db;
public EditText enter;
public TextView tv;
public ArrayList<String> listWord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewAnimator viewAnimator = new  ViewAnimator(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout front =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.front,viewAnimator );
    LinearLayout back =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.back,viewAnimator );

    viewAnimator.addView(front);
    viewAnimator.addView(back);

    setContentView(viewAnimator);
    viewAnimator.showNext();
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following lines:

```
LinearLayout front =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.front,viewAnimator);
LinearLayout back =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.back,viewAnimator);
```

because when you provide `viewAnimator` as root view during inflation, then the same root view is returned, and in your code causing the `ClassCastException` because `ViewAnimator` cannot be cast'ed into `LinearLayout`.

For your reference:

> **public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)**
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> **resource**  ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g.,
>   R.layout.main_page)
>
> **root**  Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.
>
> ***Returns***
>
> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied,
>   this is the root View; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML
>   file.

Simply provide **null** as root view and it work just fine. For example:

```
LinearLayout front = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.front, null);
LinearLayout back = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.back, null);
```